# Autoscale google app engine flexible environment depending on number of unacknowledged PubSub messages

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I would like to know if it's possible to scale the number workers depending on the number of unacknowledged pubsub messages.

I have an API service that publishes messages to a queue and then the workers processes these messages. These process jobs can take anywhere between 1 to 5 minutes and I want to be able to scale up the number of instances as my application grows. I also want to be able to scale down to 0 to save costs if there are no messages running for N number of minutes since these instances I want to spin up will be high CPU services that are expensive to keep alive.

One solution I have is running a small cloud function instance that is constantly polling the pubsub queue to see how many un'acked messages there are and then manually spinning up instances as needed.

Is this solution the idiomatic way when using GCP Flex? I know there is a way to do it with compute : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cloud-monitoring-metrics#scale_based_on_pubsub

Any real world or practice advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no: App Engine flex doesn't scale to 0, so your design can meet one of your expectation.

A better design is to use Cloud Run:

- Package your code in a container
- Deploy the container on Cloud Run and set the timeout to 10 minutes (for example). Set also the correct number of CPUs/Memory and the concurrency parameter (concurrency means the number of PubSub messages that will be processed on the same Cloud Run instance)
- Create PubSub Push subscription to invoke the Cloud Run service (be sure that your PubSub subscription has the correct permission to invoke it.) Also, set the PubSub ack deadline between 5 and 10 minutes to allow long processing on Cloud Run.

That should be OK for the foundation. You could have additional constraints (network, number of CPUs,...), let us know if you want to refine that design.

Comment: Interesting solution and I think that would work. One concern I have is that in the future I may be doing video transcoding and I may need a CPU optimized machine which leads me to believe that both cloud run & app flex might not be sufficient in term of speed & compute power. I may need to actually resort to compute engine and use instance groups. But for now, I may be able to leverage cloud run until I need those CPU optimized machines.

Comment: Hmmm, you will see. The Cloud Run team is working to integrate GPU to Cloud Run. I don't have any ETA for the alpha or the beta, but it's in the roadmap. In addition, I recommend you to have a look to Cloud Batch. With your Cloud Run that received the message, you could start a Cloud Batch with GPU/CPU (custom compute engine) to run your batch on powerful machine. At the end of the batch, the compute engine is automatically destroyed. It could be an interesting way to explore